# Исполнить javascript в qt python

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, qt4, pyside

```py
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit


def loadPage(url):
    js = """
        function loadMoreGames()
        {
            var winScroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            $('#preload').css('top', winScroll + 100);
            preload_show();
            updater.doc_update('tournament-results');
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            tournamentPagePassiveTable = true;
            tournamentSubPage = true;
            load_geoIP_clientIP(function(){
                showTournamentPage('results');
                lsClientRegisterCallbacksForTournamentPage();
                fs_update.register_actions();
                show_iframe_top_messages();
            });
        });
    """

    page = QtWebKit.QWebPage()
    loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()  # Create event loop

    page.mainFrame().loadFinished.connect(loop.quit)  # Connect loadFinished to loop quit
    page.mainFrame().load(url)
    page.mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript(js)

    loop.exec_()  # Run event loop, it will end on loadFinished
    return page.mainFrame().toHtml()


def Games(url):
    tree = loadPage(url)
    print(tree)


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

Games('http://www.myscore.ru/football/austria/tipico-bundesliga/results/')
app.exit()
```

Хочу на странице выполнить `javascript` и вытащить `html` страницы уже после выполнения скрипта. Нужно сделать клик на "Показать больше матчей" и тогда должны подгрузиться остальные игры. Не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас выполнение js-скрипта происходит до того как страница загрузилась.

Запускаете загрузку страницы, ожидаете окончания загрузки, после вызываете js-скрипт:

```
page = QtWebKit.QWebPage()
page.mainFrame().load(url)

loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()  # Create event loop
page.mainFrame().loadFinished.connect(loop.quit)
loop.exec_()

page.mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript(js)
```

А если тот клик вызывает прогрузку страницы, то и после js нужно тоже ожидание запустить. Однако, если `loadFinished` не вызывается (например, url не поменялось), то можно попробовать сделать задержку по времени, иначе код дальше не пойдет  – сигнал `loadFinished` не придет:

```
# Задержка на 5 секунд
loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()  # Create event loop
QTimer.singleShot(5000, loop.quit)
loop.exec_()
```

Comment: То что было надо.